# Why timing of FindRoot is almost the same even if the function is speedup significantly

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

This question is almost the same issue as [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40970/4742). However, it seems that it didn't draw enough attention. Now I encountered the same problem.

I previously make [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113190/4742), I will copy the code here. below code defines a function `func1` and a value `num`,

```
n = 100;
block = Symmetrize[RandomReal[1., {n, n}], Symmetric[{1, 2}]];
diagF = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> Normal /@ #] &;
mat = diagF[{block, block, block, block}];
dim = Length@mat;
eigs = Transpose@Sort@Transpose@Eigensystem@mat;
eigsdensity = {eigs[[1]], Abs[eigs[[2]]]^2};
fermiCom = 
  Compile[{{e, _Real}, {u, _Real}, {t, _Real}}, 
   Module[{tmp}, tmp = Exp[(u - e)/t]; tmp = 1./(1. + tmp); 
    tmp = 1. - tmp], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
Clear[fermi];
fermi[e_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := fermiCom[e, u, t];
num = Length@Select[eigs[[1]], # < 0 &] + 1;
Clear[func1];
func1[u_] := 
 Total[Sum[
   eigsdensity[[2, i]] fermi[eigs[[1, i]], u, 0.0001], {i, 1, dim}]]
```

now I want to find the root like this

```
FindRoot[func1[u] - num == 0, {u, -100,100}]// RepeatedTiming
(*{0.179, {u -> 0.0407121}}*)
```

it is pretty fast, however not fast enough, since it is the bottleneck of my code, I need it to be faster.

I found the `func1` itself have performance issue. Timing shows

```
func1[1.] // RepeatedTiming
(*{0.0500, 256.}*)
```

I could significantly improve the speed of `func1` by defining it like

```
Clear[func2];
func2[u_] := (fermiList = 
   Table[fermi[eigs[[1, i]], u, 0.0001], {i, 1, dim}]; 
  Total[eigsdensity[[2]]* fermiList, 2])
```

Now

```
func2[1.] // RepeatedTiming
(*{0.0021, 256.}*)
```

25 times speedup, but... look at `FindRoot` again

```
FindRoot[func2[u] - num == 0, {u, -100,100}]// RepeatedTiming
(*{0.117, {u -> 0.0407121}}*)
```

**Nothing significantly speed up !! Why?? Shouldn't be 25 times faster?**

**Making `func2[u_]` into `func2[u_?NumericQ]` can reduce timing to 0.041, but still not the anticipated speed up.**

How to correctly make it faster?

---

**update**

current comment and answer argue that the timing of `FindRoot` is much related to the internal process which could be much longer than the evaluation of my function.

I definitely can't agree on this. Here is a simple demonstration to prove this

```
FindRoot[Sin[1/x] == 0.5, {x, -1, 100000000}, 
 StepMonitor :> Print["Step to x = ", x]]
```

When evaluate the above, it shows that there are approximately 30 steps, and how much will this `FindRoot` takes?

```
FindRoot[Sin[1/x] == 0.5, {x, -1, 100000000}] // RepeatedTiming
(*{0.00060, {x -> 1.90986}}*)
```

This is so fast. You see there are no supposed overhead in the internal process

---

**update 2**

After reconsider the timing result, I think I have to ask why `func1` is faster than expected.

As you can see `func1[1.]` takes 0.05s while `FindRoot` using `func1` takes 0.179s, this is the time of only 3 evaluations!! However the `StepMonitor` clearly shows that there are much more than 3 steps.

As for `FindRoot` using `func2`, as I said, it should be faster.

Sander has mentioned the root finding algorithm. According to wikipedia, `Brent` method is actually a combination of the bisection method, the secant method and inverse quadratic interpolation. It is not that complex, just more condition branch which I think won't take too much time.

For my particular `func`, as I mentioned in another post, it has a good property, that is monotonic. So `bisection` is simple and robust for this task. Here I implemented a `bisection`, and shows a normal linear timing dependence on `func`.

```
Clear[bisection]
bisection[func_, a1_, a2_] := Module[{x1, x2, x3, f1, f2, f3},
  x1 = a1; x2 = a2;
  f1 = func[x1]; f2 = func[x2];
  If[f1*f2 < 0,
   Do[
    x3 = x1 - f1*(x2 - x1)/(f2 - f1);
    f3 = func[x3];
    If[Abs[f3] < 10.^-6,(*Print["got it","\t","step = ",i]*)Break[]]; 
    If[f1*f3 < 0, x2 = x3; f2 = f3, x1 = x3; f1 = f3];
    , {i, 1, 100}], 
   Print["two initial function values must be one positive and one \
negative"]]; x3]
```

define

```
Clear[func1new];
func1new[u_] := func1[u] - num;
Clear[func2new];
func2new[u_] := func2[u] - num;
```

and we have these timings

```
In[229]:= Table[func1new[u], {u, 1, 20}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[229]= {2.32441, Null}

In[230]:= Table[func2new[u], {u, 1, 20}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[230]= {0.102519, Null}

In[231]:= bisection[func1new, -100, 100] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[231]= {2.7258, 0.0697169}

In[232]:= bisection[func2new, -100, 100] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[232]= {0.119729, 0.0697169}

In[233]:= FindRoot[func2new[u] == 0, {u, -100, 100}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[233]= {0.289189, {u -> 0.0697169}}

In[234]:= FindRoot[func1new[u] == 0, {u, -100, 100}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[234]= {0.423125, {u -> 0.0697169}}
```

As you can see, my `bisection` shows linear timing dependence for `func1new` and `func2new`. While `FindRoot`'s behavior is odd, mysteriously fast for `func1new` and slow for `func2new`

---

**update 3**

If we add `?_NumericQ`

```
Clear[func1new];
func1new[u_?NumericQ] := func1[u] - num;
Clear[func2new];
func2new[u_?NumericQ] := func2[u] - num;
```

Then linear dependence is restored for `FindRoot`

```
In[568]:= FindRoot[func1new[u] == 0, {u, -100, 100}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[568]= {2.50487, {u -> 0.0785305}}

In[569]:= FindRoot[func2new[u] == 0, {u, -100, 100}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[569]= {0.112653, {u -> 0.0785305}}
```

Comment: What on earth makes you think there's a linear relationship between function speed and finding the roots? In many (most) cases, the time is spent in the surrounding internal machinations. Add step/evaluation monitors, and put a dummy counter in your function to count how many calls it gets - you may be surprised. Then, when you've observed that, add `?NumericQ` to the argument in your two versions of `func`... you should find the result educational.

Comment: @ciao Hi, ciao. I don't quite understand your claim. The three `func` versions produced the same result. Why will there be any difference in internal steps? As I tested, the internal processes are exactly the same. `FindRoot[func[u] - num == 0, {u, -100, 100},  StepMonitor :> Print["Step to u = ", u]]` for all three `func` version. On the other hand, the most time cosuming part in finding root is calculate the function values at different point, Why shouldn't we expect a linear relationship??

Comment: `Clear[func2];
func2[u_]...` gives me a factor of 2 or so improvement. As for general speed issue, others note it has more to do with `FindRoot` than function evaluation speed. Which means various options and possibly `Method` suboptions will need to be tried for purposes of speed tuning.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Hi, DanielLichtblau. I see many upvotes on ciao's comment and also Sander's, but I just still don't get the point. The stepmonitor shows the same for `func1` and `func2`, now `func2` is 25 times faster than `func1`. But the speed of whole process is not that different. What did `FindRoot` spend its time on?

Comment: I just noticed a similar discussion here as one below my answer. I hope the following clarifies it better. If every FindRoot evaluation step takes 1 second, and every func evaluation takes 0.02 seconds, then after 20 steps, you will have spent 20.4 seconds. Improving func's performance with 90%, hence it will now take 0,002 seconds, brings down your evaluation time to 20.04 seconds. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Sander I updated my post, have a look

Comment: So did I ... if still unclear, I added a wikipedia link with necessary backgound.

Comment: Titus, the fact that it SHOULD be simple does apparently not mean that the actual approach taken by FindRoot IS simple. It seems, FindRoot does something unnessessary magical and expensive for your purposes, logical or not, like it or not, it slows things down! Why not compile your bisection algorithm and use that instead of FindRoot?

Comment: @Sander I found adding `_?NumericQ` brings things to normal. see my update. Though I still don't know what has `FindRoot` done to `func1` without NumericQ to make it unexpectedly fast. As you said, we'd better just accept this. Thank you very much for the considerable time you have spent on my post

Answer (score 6):

`FindRoot` is slowing this down, rather than your function `func`.

---

UPDATE 1

If every `FindRoot` evaluation step takes 1 second, and every `func` evaluation takes 0.02 seconds, then after 20 steps, you will have spent 20.4 seconds. Improving `func`'s performance with 90%, hence it will now take 0,002 seconds, brings down your evaluattion time to 20.04 seconds.

---

UPDATE 2

Have a look at the search algorithm that is used here at [Wikipedia's page on Brent's search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method).

Your `func` is difficult and `Sin` `roots` are easy to discover. Without going into detail on the algorithm, imagine finding the highest peak when there is one mountain peak and there is a very thick fog, so you cannot see the peak (mathematical similar to having one place where the derivative is zero) which is easy ... continue taking a step towards the steepest slope and you will get there. If there are however many mountains, with different peak altitudes, this `steepest ascent` method does not work and you have to take a much more complex approach (as taking many more steps may simply not work or take too long). There are many places with a Derivative of zero, it is expensive to guarantee you found them all, remember there is fog, and your `func` is not simply predictable like `Sin`.

This is where your `Sin` example is treated fundamentally straightforward by the search algorithmm and `func` less so.

---

END OF UPDATES

That may explain it, but does not solve your issue. Hopefully the approach below can help you out speeding up `FindRoot` instead.

What I typically do is finetune the use of `FindRoot` by setting the `Options` for `Method`, `MaxIterations`, `AccuracyGoal` etc.

To find out about how this works out for this context, find for example the speed of conversion as follows:

```
{res, data} = Reap[FindRoot[func[u] - num == 0, {u, -100, 100}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[u]]];
ListLogPlot[data[[1]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Check out that `Method -> Brent` performs best:

```
TableForm[
 Table[
   Block[{e = 0},
   {method,
    FindRoot[func[u] - num == 0, {u, -100, 100}, Method -> method, 
        EvaluationMonitor :> e++],
   e}], 
   {method, {Automatic, "Newton", "Brent", "Secant"}}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {"Method", "fun[u]", "Evaluations"}} ]
```

[image]

After playing around with other settings, you can subsequently increase performance (at a penalty of decreased accuracy in this example) and cutting the first several iterations out by improving starting point approaches an acceptable accuracy:

```
FindRoot[func[u] - num == 0, {u, -100, 100}] // AbsoluteTiming
FindRoot[func[u] - num == 0, {u, -100, 100}, Method -> "Brent", 
    MaxIterations -> 15] // AbsoluteTiming
FindRoot[func[u] - num == 0, {u, -1, 1}, Method -> "Brent", 
    MaxIterations -> 15] // AbsoluteTiming

{0.306293, {u -> 0.00242511}}
{0.217473, {u -> 0.00207048}}
{0.223452, {u -> 0.00242421}}
```

Comment: Hi, Sander, thank you very much for the answer. But my point in my post is that "why speed up func has no effect on speed of `FindRoot` even though the internal steps are exactly the same?" It seems that you havn't explained this in your answer

Comment: I guess it is implicit. If every FindRoot evaluation step takes 1 second, and every func evaluation takes 0.02 seconds, then after 20 steps, you will have spent 20.4 seconds. Improving func's performance with 90%, hence it will now take 0,002 seconds, brings down your evaluattion time to 20.04 seconds. I updated my answer for completeness.

Comment: I update my post again, have a look again : )

Comment: Nice research, will look into it ..... but it will be tomorrow :)